# at a rate or at the rate?

Tags: grammar, articles

He was going at ***a*** rate of 50 miles per hour.

OR

He was going at ***the*** rate of 50 miles per hour.

Which one is the most appropriate grammatically speaking and why?

Comment: In this specific example, you can just say "He was going at 50 miles per hour" and avoid the whole question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct. Generally speaking, which is appropriate depends on the context.

In many contexts, including those you quote, you can use either. The distinction is a subtle one.

For example, it sounds more natural to say:

> This device works best at **a** rate of between 100 and 200 rpm.

Because it can be any rate within that range. 
But you could use either article in:

> This device works best at **a/the** rate of 100 rpm.

The following example requires **the** because it refers to a specific rate and context:

> **The** rate at which he was travelling posed a danger to other traffic.

In short, you simply have to decide which article fits your sentence better.